# How to apply shared preference to checkbox

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox, sharedpreferences, android-checkbox

I am new to android development I created a checkbox and how to save check/uncheck using share preference

```
final Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addNewBubble();
                add.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.add_fb);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                isCheckedValue = isChecked;

            }
        });

    }


private void addNewBubble() {
        BubbleLayout bubbleView = (BubbleLayout)LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.bubble_layout, null);
        bubbleView.setOnBubbleRemoveListener(new BubbleLayout.OnBubbleRemoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBubbleRemoved(BubbleLayout bubble) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);



            }
        });
        bubbleView.setOnBubbleClickListener(new BubbleLayout.OnBubbleClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBubbleClick(BubbleLayout bubble) {
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PopUpWindow.class);
                in.putExtra("yourBoolName", isCheckedValue );
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
        bubbleView.setShouldStickToWall(true);
        bubblesManager.addBubble(bubbleView, 60, 20);
    }
```

There are two Check boxes in this code `add` and `add_fb` I want to make the app remember if the checkbox are checked or unchecked

Comment: you can refer to this answer if you dont know how to use `sharedPreference` at all http://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/2792812

Comment: Please explain the scenario, you want to save data and reuse in application re launch or just want to pass it some other activity.

Comment: @Ramit Yes these check-boxes are linked to button in different activity when the checked box is checked the button should appear(these parts are taken care) but when I reenter the app the check box is unchecked and the button is not shown....

Comment: `in.putExtra("yourBoolName", isCheckedValue );` is the code I am passing to make the button activate when necessary on clicking the checkbox

Comment: Then use shared preference to save your data and read it when you start activity and then do action what you want(set check box and button) Take help of answers posted here. In case of any difficulty let us know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        if(preferences.contains("checked") && preferences.getBoolean("checked",false) == true) {
           checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }else {
            checkBox.setChecked(false);

        }
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    editor.putBoolean("checked", true);
                    editor.apply();
                }else{
                    editor.putBoolean("checked", false);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and add an explanation of how your code solves the problem?

Comment: Sure, when you enter your app firstly and click checkbok, checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(...) will work and your sharedpreference will keep checked key which the value is true. And when you enter your app next time you have already kept checked key in your preference. For this reason if(...) statement is true and your checkbox will checked

Comment: @GunayAbdullayeva Even though I unchecked the checkbox, next time when I enter the app its shows like the box is checked why is that so?the code remembers the check we have did but the It forgets the action which its meant to do.

Comment: Can you? please it would really mean a lot to me and i have updated the balance code  `in.putExtra("yourBo‌​olName", isCheckedValue );` is the code I am passing to make the button activate when necessary on clicking the checkbox

Comment: if it is hard to understand my code, i can explain. when you call checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(...) method if(...) statement will check that your checkBox is checked or not. if checkBox is checked your checked key will true else false and checked key will be kept in your sharedpreference. When you enter your app if(...) statement will be checked if it is true checkBox.setChecked(true) will call else other statement will call

Answer (score 0):

```
final String FILE_NAME = "com.myproject.prefs";
final Boolean ADD = "add";
final Boolean ADD_FB = "add_fb";

// prefs file..
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Activity.PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

// by default both will be unchecked..
checkBoxAdd.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(ADD, false);
checkBoxAddFb.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(ADD_FB, false);

// now on checkedchancedEvent update the preferences
checkBoxAdd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

         editor.putBoolean(ADD, isChecked);
         editor.apply();


        }
    });

// similary the second one...
checkBoxAddFb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

         editor.putBoolean(ADD_FB, isChecked);
         editor.apply();


        }
    });
```

**Updated**

- Here we store our preferences in a file of name "com.myproject.prefs". We need to store two preferences values of Boolean data type (one is add, another one is add_fb, as given in the Q).
- Now get SharePreferences and its editor objects.
- Set values of checkBoxes from stored preferences, if the preferences were not added before then set these to `false`. So, on the very first time when you run your app, these will get `false` values as there aren't any values added before.
- Whenever you want to get these preferences values 
  `pass your preferences file_name and mode to getSharedPreferences();` 

  `// then use those objects to get any specific value like` 
  `prefs.getBoolean(your_value_name, default_value);` **Already mentioned above**
- Whenever you want to change these preferences values use `SharedPreferences.Editor` object. Pass your value name and it's new value to
  `putBoolean()`. 
  **like** 
  `editor.putBoolean(your_value_name, true/false);`
  then apply the editing.

*Hope, it helps*